# How do I concatenate strings in a bash script?

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

How can I concatenate strings and variables in a shell script?

> stringOne = "foo"
>
> stringTwo = "anythingButBar"
>
> stringThree = "? and ?"

I want to output "foo and anythingButBar"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nothing special, you just need to add them to your declaration.
For example:

```
stringOne="foo"
stringTwo="anythingButBar"
stringThree=$stringOne$stringTwo
echo $stringThree
```

> fooanythingButBar

if you want the literal word 'and' between them:

```
stringOne="foo"
stringTwo="anythingButBar"
stringThree="$stringOne and $stringTwo"
echo $stringThree
```

> foo and anythingButBar

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, your prompt is noisy and obscures your answer (and a space after the dollar sign would help readability). Something like `$ stringOne="foo"`, for example. Also, the prompt shouldn't appear on an output line (the lines after the echos). Otherwise +1.

Comment: `echo ${stringOne}and${stringTwo}` if you don't want spaces

Comment: You can also do `stringThree=$stringOne" and "$stringTwo`.

Answer (score 6):

If instead you had:

```
stringOne="foo"
stringTwo="anythingButBar"
stringThree="%s and %s"
```

you could do:

```
$ printf "$stringThree\n" "$stringOne" "$stringTwo"
foo and anythingButBar
```